# Make Bitmaps listen to touch events

Tags: android, bitmap, touch

How can I add touch capabilities to a simple **bitmap**?

I've tried to create a wrapper class for a **bitmap**,
which implemented **`OnGestureListener`**,
but it didn't work.

I want to avoid extending View class to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Bitmap` per se is just a representation of an image... thus, in order to show it you will have to draw it somewhere (a `View`, in fact you always draw it on a `View`). Then, there's no way to avoid using the `View` class since all user interface widgets extend it.

In conclusion, if you want to simply set touch listeners to a single `Bitmap` you can, for instance, draw it on a `ImageView` and set the appropriate listeners. On the other hand, if you have a set of bitmaps drawn somewhere (for instance, on a `SurfaceView`), you should locate the bitmap by its coordinates (in that case, the `View` which would receive the events will be the `SurfaceView`).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your OnGestureListener implementation wired to a GestureDetector? The GestureDetector analyzes a MotionEvent and invokes the appropriate callback on the listener based on the type of movement it found.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector detector;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...
        detector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureListener());
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```