# Android Gestures: Translated and Rotated View returns to the original position when touch another View

Tags: android, gestures, motionevent, translate-animation, rotateanimation

i am using a project from [codepanda "gestureimageview"](https://github.com/codepanda-ch/android-gestureimageview) succesfully, and i've got to move and rotate any View, but, when i touch another View, whatever, my rotated View is returned to the original position and with no rotation. In some cases i've got to keep the view in the last rotated position, executing:

```
imgRotate.buildDrawingCache(false);
imgRotate.destroyDrawingCache();
```

But this option keep freezed my View imgRotate, and after that if i want to move again i have to execute:

```
imgRotate.buildDrawingCache(true);
```

Anyway, if i do that last sentence, my View is returned again to the original position.

What am i missing in my code?

Thanks guys!!!

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: These is my desire flow:
1- Translate and rotate imgRotate. OK

2- Draw imgRotate into a Bitmap. OK

3- Share mBitmap with diferent vias (WhatsApp, Line...). OK

4- Keep imgRotate with the final position rotated and translated. NOK

Comment: see my yesterdays answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue/21657145#21657145

Comment: Thanks @psKink but my point was using the codepanda project...

Comment: Finally i've got with the solution, as simple as to comment the last line inside the event @onMeasure inside the GestureImageView class as follow:

// initialiseImage();

That method obviously reinitiasised my view....

Comment: this codepanda doesnt support rotating with pivot between the fingers

Comment: this codepanda doesnt support rotating with pivot between the fingers

Comment: "rotation with pivot"...mmmh i do not know exactly what you mean but in fact you can rotate the view by two ways operating with two fingers: 1.One finger static, second one move and rotate the whole View. 2. Each finger at the end of the view and rotate synchronously....i do not guess certainly more ways to rotate a view

Comment: in both cases the pivot (the point that everything turns around) is not between your fingers but at position (0, 0)