# Rotation drawing point on image in Android

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, point, zooming

First of all I'm sorry for my English language because it is not perfect.
This is my code to moving, zooming image:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/6572cu99v9942xd/SandboxView.java

I want to rotate image also with that point called x=250 and y=200, How can I do that with saving zoom and move image?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue

Comment: Before I testing your code I want to ask, can I draw circle on image or not ?

Comment: why do you want to draw a circle on the image?

Comment: I'm using localization system, and I want to draw estimated point (circle) on map.

Comment: so use canvas.drawCircle or canvas.drawPath

Comment: okay I'm using that in my class at onDraw function, but what is the new coordinate of circle when rotation map or zooming.
could you see the class please.

Comment: see Canvas.concat() method

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeh,, thank you thank you, I really appreciate your help .... you are great one

Comment: but what? i dont know what is a correct answer since there was not a single quesrion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call Canvas.concat(Matrix) before drawing anything on the canvas