# How to multi touch and move view on image like a camera?

Tags: android, imageview, draw, multi-touch

I'm working on image multi touch events, that have an image with touchEvents like googleMaps's touchEvents( pinchZoom and move **togather** with **2** fingers ), I tried GestureImageView and cusomized it and could implement that. but I'm not sure it is correct way or there is another method for it.Is there any way to do that ?

1. also I want to show different parts of the large image by clicking on each part and show theme so that it seams that camera moves view on the image.

Is there any library or any tools for this purpose in android?
I will be appreciate if help me.
Thank you.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue

Comment: I will test it and inform the result,Thank you