# Hot to apply Gesture on imageview MultiGesture?

Tags: android, imageview, gesture-recognition

Hello I am using iamgeview gesture , I am using this reference "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319401/Simple-Gestures-on-Android"  but it is working only on image, I mean only image is draging but not imageview i want to drag complete image not only image attached to that imageivew

Please give me some code for multiple gesture 
Thanks

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue

Comment: sorry sir this is also same ImageView is FillParent and it is moving image with in Imageview But i wnat complete imaegview to move