# Zooming multiple ImageView individually in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, scale, move

I am having a Relative layout where I am adding multiple ImageViews dynamically(user selects image from gallery) and I want to scale move and zoom a particular ImageView on which the user is performing scale move and zoom. Other ImageViews should be as it in layout.
I have created ZoomableImageView class, but when i touch the ImageView the event is not detected.

ZoomableImageView.java

```
public class ZoomableImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final String TAG = "zoomableimageview";
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;


    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context) {

        this(context, null);

    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Toast.makeText(context, "View Created", 1000).show();
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    }   
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ondraw", 1000).show();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.restore();
    }
    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Detector", 1000).show();

            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            ZoomableImageView.this.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: see my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue

Comment: I have used it. but when I add a single image it works great but when i add multiple images the last image I add is only moveable and all other images cant be scaled or moved.

Comment: in my answer i have three images,  all of them can be moved,  scaled and even rotated

Comment: yes but you have taken static images i want to add images dynamically.
can you post a snippet for images being added dynamically

Comment: just call layers.add(layer);

Comment: from where?
and I have tried your code I am unable to add ViewPort object in my Layout.
Please little help.

Comment: why are you unable?  what's the problem?

Comment: ViewPort img = new ViewPort(getApplicationContext());
//  Layer l = new Layer(getApplicationContext(), img, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
//  img.layers.add(l);
  img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  ViewGroup inflate = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
  inflate.addView(img);


I am adding ViewPort like This

Comment: i dont see any setContentView

Comment: I have written above it.

Comment: so add id to a view with id == R.layout.activity_main, dont inflate it again, its completly different view after inflation

Comment: Yeah its working now. but how to add new image, as you said to add layers object to layer list but its not refreshing. when i add layer object it throws Choreograher class Exception.

Comment: How do i add more images to it dynamically?

Comment: just call layers.add(layer); and possibly invalidate()

Comment: Thank u @pskink it worked. But it doesnt zoom the images properly.
some images are zoomed but some are not.

Comment: i didn't see that:  all images can be zoomed properly,  what do you mean:  not properly?

Comment: I mean to say the images which are added out of which some images can be zoomed but some doesnt