# how to get image x and y coordinates after drag and zoom the image?

Tags: android, image, zooming, drag

In my application i want to get image x and y coordinates after drag and zoom the image. So I am using the following code.In my xml i have taken relative layout.This is relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonlayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

        </RelativeLayout>
```

In this relative layout i want to drag the image and zoom the image.So that's why I have created Image view programatically and apply the touch listener to that image view.This is the oncreate code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inventory_submit_images_activity);
relImage=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.image);
imgMarker = new ImageView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        params.leftMargin = 0;
        params.topMargin = 0;
        relImage.addView(imgMarker, params);
        imgMarker.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
bmdragImage=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_marker);
        height = bmdragImage.getHeight();
        width = bmdragImage.getWidth();
        imgMarker.setImageBitmap(bmdragImage);


        imgMarker.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

And this is the ontouch method and related methods.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            float scale = 0;
            layoutParamss = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
                       v.getLayoutParams();
            // Handle touch events here...
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  // first finger down only

                    x=(int) event.getX();
                    y=(int) event.getY();

                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                    mode1 = DRAG1;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted
                    x_cordinate=(int) event.getX();
                    y_cordinate=(int) event.getY();

                    Log.e("x_cordinate==",""+x_cordinate+" "+bmdragImage.getHeight());
                    Log.e("y_cordinate==",""+y_cordinate+" "+bmdragImage.getWidth());

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted
                    mode1 = NONE1;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode1=NONE1");              
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down..
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode1 = ZOOM1;
                        Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
                    }     

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    Log.e("ACTION_MOVE","ACTION_MOVE");

                    if (mode1 == DRAG1){ 

                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points

                    } 
                    else if (mode1 == ZOOM1){ 
                        // pinch zooming
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                        if (newDist > 5f){
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the image..
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                            height=(int) (bmdragImage.getHeight()*scale);
                            width=(int) (bmdragImage.getWidth()*scale);

                            Log.e("height int===="+scale,""+height);
                            Log.e("width int====="+scale,""+width);

                        }                                                 
                    }

                    break;          
            }

            view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen    
            return true; // indicate event was handled

        }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

This code is dragging and zooming is working fine. But my problem is getting x coordinate and y coordinate after drag the image.These x and y values are getting wrong. Because where ever i touch the image with in the relative layout, dragging is working.Because of these code in oncreate of image view params. So x and y values are getting wrong.

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

If i change the image layout params to wrap contnet like the bellow,the image dragging is with in that area only. And zooming also not working properly. But my requirement is drag the image total relative layout.And get the x and y coordinates of image view.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: see my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue