# android pinch zoom and panning for canvas, something doesn't work

Tags: android, canvas, zooming, pinch, panning

i'm trying to implement pinch zoom and panning options for canvas i'm using the code (slightly modified, i've added DisplayMetrics to automatically set devices screen size) from this webpage http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/8/

As a result i have just an image opening in app(not whole though, just a fragment cause its bigger than screen size), image is not zooming and not panning, its just rotating when i rotate the phone. I used another code before, simplier, just for the zoom and it was working. I was sitting in front of this a lot of time and i have no clue what's wrong. It looks like its all right but it doesn't work. Maybe you guys know what am i doing wrong.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class ZoomView extends View {

//These two constants specify the minimum and maximum zoom

private static float MIN_ZOOM = 1f;
private static float MAX_ZOOM = 5f;
private float scaleFactor = 1.f;
private ScaleGestureDetector detector;
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

//These constants specify the mode that we're in

private static int NONE = 0;
private static int DRAG = 1;
private static int ZOOM = 2;
private int mode;
public boolean dragged = true;

//These two variables keep track of the X and Y coordinate of the finger when it first

//touches the screen
private float startX = 0f;
private float startY = 0f;

//These two variables keep track of the amount we need to translate the canvas along the X

//and the Y coordinate
private float translateX = 0f;
private float translateY = 0f;



//These two variables keep track of the amount we translated the X and Y coordinates, the last time we                                                          //
//panned.

private float previousTranslateX = 0f;
private float previousTranslateY = 0f;

public ZoomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    detector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mode = DRAG;


//We assign the current X and Y coordinate of the finger to startX and startY minus the     previously translated
//amount for each coordinates This works even when we are translating the first time because the     initial
//values for these two variables is zero.

            startX = event.getX() - previousTranslateX;
            startY = event.getY() - previousTranslateY;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            translateX = event.getX() - startX;
            translateY = event.getY() - startY;



//We cannot use startX and startY directly because we have adjusted their values using the         previous translation values.
//This is why we need to add those values to startX and startY so that we can get the actual         coordinates of the finger.
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX() - (startX + previousTranslateX), 2)     + Math.pow(event.getY() - (startY + previousTranslateY), 2));
            if(distance > 0) {
                dragged = true;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            mode = ZOOM;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            dragged = false;

//All fingers went up, so let's save the value of translateX and translateY into     previousTranslateX and
//previousTranslate
            previousTranslateX = translateX;
            previousTranslateY = translateY;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = DRAG;

//This is not strictly necessary; we save the value of translateX and translateY into     previousTranslateX
//and previousTranslateY when the second finger goes up
            previousTranslateX = translateX;
            previousTranslateY = translateY;
            break;
    }

    detector.onTouchEvent(event);
//We redraw the canvas only in the following cases:
// o The mode is ZOOM
//        OR
// o The mode is DRAG and the scale factor is not equal to 1 (meaning we have zoomed) and dragged     is
//   set to true (meaning the finger has actually moved)

    if ((mode == DRAG && scaleFactor != 1f && dragged) || mode == ZOOM) {
        invalidate();
    }

    return true;
}


Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pozegnanie);
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor, this.detector.getFocusX(),     this.detector.getFocusY());
    canvas.translate(translateX / scaleFactor, translateY / scaleFactor);


//If translateX times -1 is lesser than zero, let's set it to zero. This takes care of the left     bound

    if((translateX * -1) < 0) {
        translateX = 0;
    }

//This is where we take care of the right bound. We compare translateX times -1 to (scaleFactor -     1) * displayWidth.
//If translateX is greater than that value, then we know that we've gone over the bound. So we     set the value of
//translateX to (1 - scaleFactor) times the display width. Notice that the terms are     interchanged; it's the same
//as doing -1 * (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth

    else if((translateX * -1) > (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth) {
        translateX = (1 - scaleFactor) * displayWidth;
    }
    if(translateY * -1 < 0) {
        translateY = 0;
    }

//We do the exact same thing for the bottom bound, except in this case we use the height of the     display
    else if((translateY * -1) > (scaleFactor - 1) * displayHeight) {
        translateY = (1 - scaleFactor) * displayHeight;
    }

//We need to divide by the scale factor here, otherwise we end up with excessive panning based on our zoom level
//because the translation amount also gets scaled according to how much we've zoomed into the canvas.


/* The rest of your canvas-drawing code */
    canvas.restore();
}


private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

And this is my activity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class zoom extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ZoomView zoom = new ZoomView(this);
    setContentView(zoom);

}
```

Comment: It was i think the best code on the web :P It's only con is that it doesnt work :D

Comment: the best one?  you are joking,  aren't you? see for example my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue

Comment: Thank you, it looks legit, i will compare it with the code i have, which started to work after few modifications, i had to draw bitmap after scaling and translating, i dont know why but the code to limit panning outside the bitmap doesnt work and zooming with focus point makes panning after zoom inproportionate. Picture moves faster than finger.

Comment: @pskink I'm the author of that "twisted, mixed up code" :). I wrote that based on a tutorial for android multi-touch. At the time (in '11), there was no gesture-detector project. Hence a lot of what that project abstracts out, I had to do manually.

Comment: @pskink I'm not an Android expert :) and I was learning things from scratch for a class project and I used the example from the Hello Android! book. If I felt the pain of writing this sort of code on a regular basis, I probably would have written a similar library (indeed, I briefly considered it but didn't get the time to follow up on it). I mainly code in Java for server-side stuff and so I am not too familiar with the whole Android API and related best-practices.