# Any ways of making pinch to zoom smoother

Tags: android, canvas

Is there any ways of implementing smooth pinch to zoom without using matrix?

I am building drawing app and I want it to have pinch to zoom.

I get pivot point for scaling with:

```
centerposX = mScaleDetector.getFocusX();
centerposY = mScaleDetector.getFocusY();
```

and for scaling then I use:

```
canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, centerposX, centerposY);
```

But the problem is that it immediately centers view at the pivot point and them zooms it, rather than using it as a guide for centering.

I've seen that this problem has been solved by using matrix, but I don't want to use them as I need to keep track of offsets, ZoomTranslations which are calculated from centerposX/Y and scaleFactor to put drawings where they belong on screen.

So is there any way to solve this pivot point problem smoothly?

Thanks!

Comment: how can Canvas.scale center a View?  and what's wrong with the Matrix,  i didn't understand your explanation...

Comment: I meant that on touch my viewport instantly jumps to point of touch. and i want to implement browser like pinch to zoom behaviour. 

And I don't want to use matrices because Drawing on scaled screen requires to keep track of lots of variables and I am not sure how i would handle them with matrixes. 

Anyways, if there isn't any solutions to solve this "jumping"behavior  I will rewrite my code.

Comment: So, I've tried to make everything with matrix. Scaling works like a charm. But there is one problem, finger drawings once again are getting misplaced when they are drawn, also they are not scaled properly.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue, maybe it will be helpful

Comment: But my onDraw() methods draws not only bitmap, but also path,and bitmap, sadly drawPath() doesnt take matrix as argument and this is main reason why I cannot use Matrix.

Comment: use Canvas.concat() then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a week I understood that I need to use matrix and get absolute coordinates on the screen, so I used Gesture detector to set matrix scale

```
matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
```

In my onDraw method I used `canvas.concat(matrix);` so not only Bitmap, but WHOLE canvas get's matrix transformation, and to get real screen coordinates I used a method i found on stack-overflow:

```
public float[] getAbsolutePosition(float Ax, float Ay) {
        matrix.getValues(m);

        float x = width - ((m[Matrix.MTRANS_X] - Ax) / m[Matrix.MSCALE_X])
                - (width - getTranslationX());

        float y = height - ((m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] - Ay) / m[Matrix.MSCALE_X])
                - (height - getTranslationY());

        return new float[] { x, y };
    }
```

I call this every time in my onTouchEvent() method, supplying event.getX and event.getY() as arguments.

After that, everything is easy peasy, also because of this beautiful method I've got rid of ~4-5 variables which I had to use to find real touch location.

Comment: or the easiest workaround is to listen to touch on the parent view, which does not zoom