# How to fetch all contact details from phone

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which retrieving all contact details(number, name, email, photo) from mobile. its showing correct all details but problem is that email id is showing same as mobile number. so how to solve this problem.code snippet is below. please help me

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS}, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
            {
                String contactNumber= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));  
                String contactName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String emailId =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
               // int phoneContactID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setConatctId(count++);
                //contact.setConatctId(phoneContactID);
                contact.setEmailId(emailId);             
                contact.setDisplayName(contactName);                   
                contact.setMobileNo(contactNumber);
```

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804387/android-fetch-all-contact-list-name-email-phone-takes-more-then-a-minute-for

Comment: i already tried this but its taking too much time

Comment: too much time???  you must be joking,  don't you? i had 60 contacts and it took in avarage 25 ms (that is 0.025 sec)

Comment: btw it was 25 ms on the **emulator**,  not on the real device

Comment: its working fine but problem is that in some contact name and email is showing same and mobile number is null and whichever has mobile number for that email is showing null

Comment: in my code mobile number is null?  i don't  get what you mean...

Comment: i mean for some contact, name and email is same and phone number is null

Comment: Paste th output written on the logcat for that contact

Comment: i think its fetching facebook id also so how can avoid it.

Comment: Paste the output of my code written on the logcat for that contact

Comment: Actually i have modified your code and removed all logcat and and its directly running on mobile

Comment: so i cannot help you as i don't see what you have changed... the Log.d was to verify everything is fetched correctly, why did you remove it then?

Comment: k but tomorrow morning i will paste the output then solve my problem

Comment: so what's the logcat output?

Comment: so what's the logcat output actually?

Answer (score 0):

It could be better to use [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) for fetching data from database using providers. And user [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) to show the content in listview.