# Is there a faster way to filter through and sort the Android Contacts list?

Tags: android, database, filtering, android-contacts, android-cursor

So I am working on a project where I need to get the user's contact list (Specifically the Name, email address, and location of the contact details), put that into a list, and then use that list in an autocomplete view so they can start typing a name and it will filter it out.

My code works just fine, it all compiles and all runs without error. The problem is that it is VERY slow. For someone who has 10 contacts, this will likely not take long, but my phone holds 1700 contacts in it so this entire process takes upwards of 2 minutes to complete... which is horrendous!

Here is the current working code below (I cut out the code for the location adding as it was wordy):

```
   public static List<MyObject> getContactList(){
        List<MyObject> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor people = MyApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver().
                query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (people.moveToNext()) {
            String email = "";
            String location = "";
            String phone = "";

            String contactName = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            if(contactId != null){
                Cursor contactsEmails = getSpecificEmailsCursor(contactId);

                while (contactsEmails.moveToNext()){
                    //For now, just setting it to the last email
                    email = contactsEmails.getString(contactsEmails.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                    phone = contactsEmails.getString(contactsEmails.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


                }
                contactsEmails.close();

                MyObject person = new MyObject();
                try{

                    person.setEmail(email);
                    person.setName(contactName);
                    person.setPhone(phone);
                } catch (NullPointerException e){
                    L.m("Null pointer hit on person");
                }
                if(contactName != null && email != null){
                    contactList.add(person);
                }
            }
        }
        people.close();
        return contactList;
    }
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to either speed this process up, or, a better way to go about what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks!

-Sil

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830)

Comment: @Pskink that definitely did the trick, ty. Do you want to post it in an answer and I will select it as the correct answer?

Comment: i'm glad it worked and you were able to get some extra data from CommonDataKinds

Comment: and now, how long does it take to load all the contacts (compared to your 2 minutes) ? i guess it is something like 5-10 seconds?

Comment: A whopping 400 milliseconds lol. Sorts through 1800 lightning fast. Very helpful, ty!

Comment: 400 ms ??????? compared to 120000 ? so it is 300 times faster? i cant believe....

Comment: Right? My guess was that mine was gaining time exponentially due to nested for loops, but not sure. either way, grateful it works so well. Now granted, when I add the images in via an InputStream so I can save them to the object, it goes back up to 22 seconds. But let's not lie. It would have likely taken an hour on my previous method!