# How to get contacts with email or phone number

Tags: android

How can I get a list of contacts that either have a phone number or an email in Android.

I'm a bit confused with the contracts and how can I join the info.

Thank you

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830)

Comment: +1 to the answer pointed to by @pskink: at the time I'm writing this comment, the solutions in this page are utterly inefficient because they use nested queries.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I fetched contacts with **email** and **phone number**. The **Contact** object is just a simple pojo that I created. This code is in an AsyncTask that I run after the user has provided permission to access **Contacts**.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

  do {
      // get the contact's information
      String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
      String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
      Integer hasPhone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

      // get the user's email address
      String email = null;
      Cursor ce = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
      if (ce != null && ce.moveToFirst()) {
          email = ce.getString(ce.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
          ce.close();
      }

      // get the user's phone number
      String phone = null;
      if (hasPhone > 0) {
          Cursor cp = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
          if (cp != null && cp.moveToFirst()) {
              phone = cp.getString(cp.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              cp.close();
          }
      }

      // if the user user has an email or phone then add it to contacts
      if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()
              && !email.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) || (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))) {
          Contact contact = new Contact();
          contact.name = name;
          contact.email = email;
          contact.phoneNumber = phone;
          contacts.add(contact);
      }

  } while (cursor.moveToNext());

  // clean up cursor
  cursor.close();
}
```

For **DISPLAY_NAME** you can use the following:

```
private final String DISPLAY_NAME = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
```

Here is a link to an [AsyncTask Example](https://gist.github.com/srayhunter/47ab2816b01f0b00b79150150feb2eb2) that I use with this.

Comment: Answer is great and now you have 10k reputation :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
              String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
              if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                 Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                           null,
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                           new String[]{id}, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only returns phone numbered contacts. Not email

Comment: @JohnSmith my example has the phone number and email address.