# Get Contact Details Given the Lookup URI

Tags: android

Given:

```
Uri contactLookupURI = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(contactID, lookupKey);
```

How do I use this to get a contact's details such as phone, email, etc?

I tried:

```
String[] CDETAIL_PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
    };


Cursor detail_cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contactLookupURI, CDETAIL_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

But I get an error saying **"Invalid column: data1"** which I guess refers to `Phone.NUMBER` field. This might be because it's referring to the Contacts table which doesn't have that field?

According to other answers, I can use the `_ID` to get the contact details but I want to use the URI only.

Also, can you tell me what

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact()
```

does? The documentation illustrates that it gives me the Content URI but how's it any different than the Lookup URI?

Answer (score 0):

You have getting **Invalid column: data1** because `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` and `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS` both have same value that's data1.
you can not directly get this information.

here is solution for get he email and Number from user https://stackoverflow.com/a/40540640/2941375