# Android - SearchView - cursor - Reyclerview empty

Tags: android, cursor, contacts

I'm trying to get contacts with their email addresses and their phone numbers.

For some reason, I only get 1 email, even though the cursor getcount returns 7790

Thank you very much for any help

public void getNameEmailDetails(){

```
    ContentResolver contactResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String photoUri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

        if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
        {
            Cursor pCur = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactId }, null);

            while (pCur.moveToNext())
            {
                String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String type = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), Integer.parseInt(type), "");


                Log.d("TAG", s + " phone: " + phone);
            }

            pCur.close();

        }

        Cursor emailCursor = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactId }, null);

        while (emailCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String phone = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            int type = emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
            String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), type, "");

            Log.d("TAG", s + " email: " + phone);
        }

        emailCursor.close();

        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830)

Comment: I was stuck for 2 days. Thank you! Awesome code! query took 0.732 s (732 ms)

Comment: and your original code took ... ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't measure it.... give me a sec :)

Comment: i bet it was more than one minute like in the case of OP who had only 700 contacts... am i right?

Comment: I'm wondering how contact ids work, some emails are grouped and some not :-/ - A lot in fact.

Comment: it is grouped by `ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID` column