# Android Contacts Fetch

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have 800+ contacts in my android mobile, when I try to upload, its taking 30 sec - 2 mins [based on internet connection] to upload to server. Is there any fastest way of doing it. I'm  actually fetching contacts, converting them to json array and storing into file and uploading to server.

Comment: Why are you storing in file? You can directly upload as json format and let server do their work.

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, are you even trying to upload the contact image by converting it into byte in your json?

Comment: Image not uploading.

Comment: #Mohit Kacha : for security resons I need to encode contact details. I use base 64 encoding for this. While doing conversion I am getting error that string cannot hold 800 contacts details.

Comment: so what is the bottleneck? slow wire? slow data access? anything else? how long does it take just to read the data without sending out?

Comment: To read all contact data and convert it to json, it takes around 30 sec - 1min (this doesn't required Internet at all)

Comment: one minute? its far too slow, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830

Comment: Thanks !pskink I searched for 1 hr but didnt find any solution, , I have to go with this.