# move an image view, which method

Tags: android

I am trying to move an imageview based on the the screen onTouchEvent .
I am wondering which one to use to move the image view as I am dragging it:

1- Using Layoutparams, set params.leftMargine and params.topMargin

2- Using set setLeft() and setTop() Method on the view

3- Using setX() and setY() method on the view

And any reason to why one would be used not used?
Thanks

Comment: instead of moving an ImageView draw the Bitmap directly using Canvas.drawBitmap

Comment: How about [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)?

Comment: Pskink, but the image view is loaded already. I don't need to decode to bitmap again. What difference would it make?

Comment: Arol_123, translate animation does not move the actual image (ie change the coordinates), it just offset the actual drawing

Comment: @Snake see one of my answers on how easily you can not only drag the `Bitmap` but also resize and rotate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue/21657145#21657145

Comment: Thank you for the link. The code is amazing. I upvoted it and placed it favourite :)

Comment: Easy,  huh?  But still 95% guys here try to move an ImageView thinking its easier...

Comment: Hehe. Yes I have to admit I was one of them. Can you please check my newest question which is released in way to this topic?

Comment: @Snake which question? "Which way to use to draw circle..." or "Draw segmented circle..." ?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I am referring to the which way to draw a circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and most important, the android vertion.
as a person with 2.3 vertion i know that it s*cks to not be able to use application because my vertion is not compatable.

the setX and setY are able from api 14 if i am not wrong and so is the setLeft and setTop.

only the layoutParams are able from api 1, si it is the best way, in my opinion