# Need implementation suggestions for Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to implement a small application with **canvas on surface view** and added some Bmp images on that canvas as shown in attached image.

[Click here to check the requirement in image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzvu-ntt8WHPcE1zQno4MW9mUGs/view?usp=sharing)

Here A,B,C,D,E and Bmp1 are bitmaps and all can move.
Below is my requirements:

1. I want to drag bitmap on another bitmap like i want to drag bmpA from left to right over Bmp1(Now if i am trying to do like that they are merging).
2. I want to know where i have touched on the screen like i touched on Bmp1 or touched on A or B or C.... or empty canvas area.(Now i can recognize whether i have touched Bmp1 or other by using below code.

   ```
   if (mTouched_x >= Bibox.getCurrentPosition().x && mTouched_x < (Bibox.getCurrentPosition().x + BBoxBmp.getWidth()) && mTouched_y >= Bibox.getCurrentPosition().y && mTouched_y < (Bibox.getCurrentPosition().y + BBoxBmp.getHeight()))
       return true;
   else
       return false;
   ```

But I want to know whether I have touched other Bmp's or not because A,B,C..  are dynamic bmp's and number may increase.

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: i so far created a class **CustomSurfaceView** extends _SurfaceView implements Runnable, OnDragListener_. Here i created a class to maintain properties of those bitmaps. And i am first time working on **Canvas** i am not getting any hint to implement those

Comment: why OnDragListener? you are drawing your Bitmaps in SurfaceView, so do the drag by yourself

Comment: Yes i want to drag Bitmaps and i need to create one connection between those if those are in close.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830, on how i did similar thing

Comment: @pskink : Thankyou for your response. You created those by extending **View** and you are used some _layout_ (If my guess is correct).But i retirement is use  **SurfaceView and Canvas**

Comment: there is no big difference: both use Canvas

Comment: and i checked your example. My requirement and your suggestion both are not matching :(

Comment: well points 1) and 2) are met...

Comment: @pskink sorry to say your application is not working in my Mot G2 mobile

Comment: not working?   ׂׂׂׂׂ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ImageView Scaling and translating issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue)