# Move ImageView inside RelativeLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have An imageView with android:scaleType="matrix"

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I want to drag this `ImageView` to left to look at the parts of image which were off screen.

In other words I want to move this image to the point where I mark the point on `ImageView`.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: so `*Translate()` your Matrix

Comment: How can i translate my Matrix?

Comment: use preTranslate/postTranslate

Comment: onTuch Event i got the (X,Y)point but i want to move the image without touching on screen like in map when you search the location image move to that spacific location,  Followiing code is from OnTuch Event:     matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
      - start.y);

Comment: can you please post some code snip?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Imageview Inside Framelayout and use following code to move it :

Java Code:

```
_frameLayout.setX(Position);

_frameLayout.setY(Position);
```

Example XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_material_dark" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: How  i calculate X and Y position?

Comment: Can you please tell me??

Comment: float yAxis = 0.0f; int dragDistance = 200;

yAxis = event.getRawY() - dragDistance * 3 / 2;

int mathValue = (int) Math.round(yAxis);

 _frameLayout.setY(mathValue); 

This will move your frame in vertical

Comment: This code  move the whole framelayout i just want to move imgae ... i also applied panning and zooming functionality on that image. i just want that this image behave like google map. onTuch event when i drag that image to left i can see the hidden part of that image but the only thing i want the auto move the image to the current location (which was hidden). hope you understand my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ImranAhmad I just showed a way, and this is not the whole layout, here framelayout is just a small part of the layout & in that framelayout only imageview is present. Using this example u can smartly design ur layout. Here I showed framelayout just to show how to move your imageview over layout