# How to stop Image From scaling when MATRIX is set

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener, touch-event, ontouch

I am dragging , moving , zooming and rotating my image , all is working fine. but I have serious problem and that is my Image flicker due to some problem and starts appear from the top of screen. First let me show my code what I am doing and then I will tell you

**What I have done **

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);



        float scale;

        // Dump touch event to log
       // dumpEvent(event1);

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
                break;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    toggleSaveButtonState();

                    // ...
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
//                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
//                            - start.y);

                    matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                    matrixX = matrixValues[2];
                    matrixY = matrixValues[5];
                    width = matrixValues[0] * (((view).getDrawable()
                            .getIntrinsicWidth() / 2));
                    height = matrixValues[4] * (((view).getDrawable()
                            .getIntrinsicHeight() / 2));


                    dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    float newX = event.getX() - start.x;
                    Log.v("bounds out", "matrixsX=" + matrixX+ " dx" + dx);
                            //if image will go outside left bound
                    if (matrixX + dx < 0-width){
                        dx = -matrixX-width;


                        Log.v("bounds", "matrixsX=" + matrixX + " dx" + dx + " width" + width + "image width  = " + view.getWidth()/2);
//                        if (dx != -0.0) {
//
//                            //  dx=(float)-0.0;
//                        }}
                         }
                    //if image will go outside right bound
                    if (matrixX + dx + width > view.getWidth()) {
                        dx = view.getWidth() - matrixX - width;

                        Log.v("bounds", "matrixsX=" + matrixX + " dx" + dx + " width" + width + "image width  = " + view.getWidth());
                    }
                    //if image will go oustside top bound
                    if (matrixY + dy < 0) {
                        dy = -matrixY;

                    }
                    //if image will go outside bottom bound
                    if (matrixY + dy + height > view.getHeight()) {
                        dy = view.getHeight() - matrixY - height;

                    }
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

                } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float currentScale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                        if (scale * currentScale > MAX_ZOOM) {
                            scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScale;
                        }
                        else if (scale * currentScale < MIN_ZOOM)
                        {   scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScale;}

                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null) {
                        newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                                view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
        // Perform the transformation
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        return true; // indicate event was handled

    }
```

This piece of code I think you can found almost all over every where I have slightly updated it to put some limits such as going off the screen etc.

**Problem **

When I start my application I want it to be appear in bottom but some how it sticks to middle , and when I touch the image view it flicks , it looks like that it starts it self from top corner and then come down to the point where we have touched it and Also it becomes bigger on some devices and smaller on some devices.

I think this is due to this line.

> view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

if I remove this line and put this line in xml such as

> android:scaleType="matrix"

Then My image stick to the top which I do not want to be happen

So what can I do and How can I make things possible this is what I want

**What I Want**

1. I want my Image to show on the bottom of the screen
2. I want my image never gets flicking effect and should never be re sized
3. I want the touch to be happen when touch on the image inside the Image view

Please tell me How can I get my desired results.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830)

Comment: I think this is not helpful as my code and working principal is different

Comment: so it seems you have to fight with the `ImageView`, the bad choice...

Comment: yeah , what else I could do

Comment: can you tell me why my image goes to top when I set scaletype to matrics  in xml

Comment: what is your `Matrix` ?

Comment: i dont know , i set in xml like this

Comment: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/suit_1"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />

Comment: read ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX documentation

Comment: I tried but unable to under stand

Comment: do you know any way to set the scaleType = Matrix and still setting the image to bottom

Comment: so if you dont understand it, use simple solution: i posted the link

Comment: how can and where I should use that image