# Move And Scale Canvas After onScale (Zoom in View)

Tags: android, bitmap, zooming, android-canvas, scale

I'm developing an app in Android where I customize an View and I draw some canvas with Bitmap. This bitmap are dirrent among them. 
So I'm able to move them with  finger ( generating an ontouchevent ).
If I decide to do the pinch to zoom IN OR OUT they can not move them or can not but remain in the portion of the screen that was before zooming out

I do not know if I have explained very well , but it is difficult to exert. I googled or everywhere but found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: leave `Canvas` as it is, better use `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)`

Comment: but how to move my canvas after set matrix ?

Comment: you dont move the `Canvas`, move the `Matrix` instead, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830)

Comment: But I Use an OnTouchEvent for all elements, how to move these with more matrix

Comment: do you understand me ? @pskink

Comment: sorry but no, i don't

Comment: in My CustomView.class i use ONE  method to move all object it is called ontouchevent, do you understand me ? How to move my object inside the ontouchevent with matrix? @pskink

Comment: have you seen the answer i linked ?

Comment: Yes but i don't undeerstand very well

Comment: I want zoom in-out view not element