# Android: object(ImageView) reposition after background ImageView is scaled

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

In my application, i want to write an application that when i scale and move anywhere in the background ImageView. Then, the black-colored Imageview will also **scale and re-position** to the according position. For example, if i place an imageview at (100,100)(center position or you can think that there is a mark on the bg), then after scaling the bg, the imageview is still stayed on this mark. The action is described as shown in the Fig. .  For the "move", it works perfect for me. However, for multi-finger touch like the red arrow, it moves to a **wrong position**(scaling is right)......
Here is my code for two finger touch scaling the bg,

**MainActivity**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
    ImageView ca = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            view = (ImageView) v;
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
                     matrix.set(view.getImageMatrix());
                     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                     LayoutParams aaa = (LayoutParams) ca.getLayoutParams();
                     start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                     mode = DRAG;
                     break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted
                    move_x = event.getX()-start.x;
                    move_y = event.getY()-start.y;
                    float[] pts = {0.0f,0.0f};
                    Matrix m_image = imageView.getImageMatrix();
                    m_image.mapPoints(pts);
                    laststop.x = pts[0];
                    laststop.y = pts[1];
                    if (mode == DRAG) { 
                            LayoutParams aaaa = (LayoutParams) ca.getLayoutParams();    
                            int caLeft = aaaa.leftMargin;
                            int caTop = aaaa.topMargin;
                            aaaa.leftMargin = caLeft + (int)(move_x);
                            aaaa.topMargin  = caTop  + (int)(move_y);
                            ca.setLayoutParams(aaaa);
                            ca.invalidate();
                    }
                    mode = NONE;
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted
                    if (mode == ZOOM){
                        scale_new = scale * scale_new;
                        if(ca != null && ca.freeze == true){
                            LayoutParams aa = (LayoutParams) ca.getLayoutParams();
                            int width_ori = aa.width;
                            int height_ori = aa.height;
                            int center_x = aa.leftMargin + width_ori/2;
                            int center_y = aa.topMargin  + height_ori/2;

                            aa.width = (int) (width_ori * scale);
                            aa.height = (int) (height_ori * scale);

                            aa.leftMargin = (int) ((center_x - aa.width/2)/scale);
                            aa.topMargin = (int) ((center_y - aa.height/2)/scale);

                            ca.setLayoutParams(aa);
                            ca.invalidate();
                        }
                    }

                            mode = NONE;
                            break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: 
                     oldDist = spacing(event);
                     if (oldDist > 5f) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        midPoint(mid, event);
                        mode = ZOOM;
                     }
                          break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) { 
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); 

                    } else if (mode == ZOOM) { 
                        newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 5f) {
                                  matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                  scale = newDist / oldDist; 
                                  matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        }
                    }
                break;
            }
            view.setImageMatrix(matrix); 
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Fig. 1 [image]

Comment: and what is your problem actually?

Comment: why is it wrong? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: ok, i will ask again: why is it wrong? what is the right position then?

Comment: the object(or said the imageview) is run to a unexcepted place....I am wondering why too

Comment: simply dont use an `ImageView` for that: it only makes your code more complex, instead draw your `Bitmaps` by yourself

Comment: In my application, i want to add multi-object into the background, after confirm the object is fixed at that position, object will move as the background scale or move

Comment: i hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830) will help you