# How to drag image after zooming it??

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, motionevent

I followed a simple tutorial on how to zoom an image. The problem is i can't drag and scale the image after zooming it. i did read android Dragging and scalling and tried other answers but it doesn't work. below is the code for zooming in the image. Can someone guide me here?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ImageView imageView;
    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    Float scale=1f;
    ScaleGestureDetector SGD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SGD= new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());

    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
           scale= scale*detector.getScaleFactor();
            scale= Math.max(0.1f,Math.min(scale,3f));
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
    }
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830)

Comment: Great! thank you. it's a little bit confusing for me. Can you please summarize the process for me?

Comment: confusing? all it does is a `Matrix` transforming: all (dragging, scaling and rotating) is done in `Matrix` transformation

Comment: nevermind, it worked. THANKS AGAIN pskink!

Comment: @pskink this solution you gave me is very effective for image taken from drawable, how do i get the same result if i set the imageView from an URL? i've been trying again and again but still couldn't get the result i  want. can you help me again ?

Comment: There is really no difference where you get the Bitmap from

Comment: @pskink your code worked well for my APP but i wanted to ask you about the zooming part.when i try to zoom in to the point i want, it will zoom to the center of the screen  instead to the point i want, i tried playing with the point x and y to get the result i want but it didn't work. can you guide me how to zoom in exactly to the point i want?

Comment: see `Matrix#postScale(float sx, float sy, float px, float py)`, the last two parameters: `px` and `py` define the scale pivot point

Comment: all right, let me see what i can do