# How do i drag drop and zoom four images inside one single layout

Tags: android

Four static images inside one layout.
No use by using this below code.

```
 @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(midPoint, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x, event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                return true;
            }


            private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }

            private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);

                point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please explain more what the problem is and what you tried. I cleaned up the code for you so it is easier to read.

Comment: i want to drag,drop and zoom images inside one layout..i have tried using Touchlistener with above code,where im getting drap and zoom only for single image not all the images.hope,u understand.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830