# Issues with zoom and Canvas using ScaleGestureDetector

Tags: android, zooming, android-canvas

I am trying to implement zoom in my app. But I have encountered difficulties.

What I have done so far:

(NOTE: this app is a game, so it does not use `invalidate` but a thread)

Rendering and the scaling:

```
public void render(Canvas c) {
    super.draw(c);

    if (c != null) {
        int ss = c.getSaveCount();
        c.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        //Rendering stuff
        c.restoreToCount(ss);
    }
}
```

Current zoom:

(this is called from onTouchEvent in the master class when there are two pointers. THese classes are nested. )

```
class scaler extends ScaleGestureDetector {
    public scaler(Context context, OnScaleGestureListener listener) {
        super(context, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        listener.onScale(this);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public float getScaleFactor() {
        return super.getScaleFactor();
    }
}
float startScale;
float endScale;
class ScaleListener implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener{


        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            startScale = detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = (scaleFactor < 1 ? 1 : scaleFactor); // prevent our view from becoming too small //
            scaleFactor = ((float)((int)(scaleFactor * 100))) / 100; // Change precision to help with jitter when user just rests their fingers //
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        }


}
```

I have been looking on several questions on SO, and all I have found does not work properly. There are various reasons for the solutions.

The one I am currently using:

Zooms in before zooming out(the scalefactor drops down before zooming out)

It does not zoom in on the area the fingers are in.

So how can I add zoom that zooms in on the area the fingers are in, and make a it so it zooms without resetting the zoom so it is really zoomed in?

Comment: do not override `ScaleGestureDetector#onTouchEvent`: you have to call this method from your `MotionEvent` dispatching method

Comment: I don't follow. Are you saying that I should call ScaleListener(the class I have) `.onScale()` from OnTouchEvent in the SurfaceView?(I call ScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent from SurfaceView.onTouchEvent)

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html (the second bullet)

Comment: Which part? Read through it, several times too. I cannot find anything there that helps me  The link is documentation, not anything on integration

Comment: (the second bullet)

Comment: and no, you shouldnt extend `ScaleGestureDetector` at all

Comment: This is my first go at zooming. I don't really know what I'm doing, and why I should/should not do some things.

Comment: so in the link i posted you can find: `"To use this class: ..."`

Comment: Create an instance for the view(the `scaler`-class) and call onTouchEvent in ScaleGestureDetector from onTouchEvent in the view

Comment: yes, exactly, and your listener methods will be called

Comment: Automatically??

Comment: yes, isn't it magical?

Comment: I was not aware of that.Testing it results in it being smooth and not zooming in completely, but it still doesn't zoom around the fingers

Comment: just add some `Log.d` inside every listener method (`onScale*`) to see when they are called

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830, you can remove MoveGestureDetector and RotateGestureDetector and use only ScaleGestureDetector

Comment: I am using SurfaceView and OnTouchEvent so I haven't had a need to use MoveGestureDetector or RotateGestureDetector. Using offset I have movement, and I have no need for rotation.

Comment: so thats why i said you can remove them and just test ScaleGestureDetector

Comment: I have tested it and now only one issue remains: Zooming in around the fingers

Comment: `"Zooming in around the fingers"` which means?

Comment: For an instance in a browser on your phone: If you want to see a picture, but the site isn't designed for mobile, so you have to zoom to see it. Then you would expect it to zoom in on the picture, and not have the X and Y coordinates to have the same position(e.g. 0,0). Does that make sense?

Comment: not really, you mean that scaling pivot point (the pixel that does not change during the scaling) should be between your fingers?

Comment: Yes. I tried using setPivot[X/Y] but it didn't change the zoom area

Comment: did you try my code? doesn't it work that way?

Comment: From the link you sent earlier?[(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue/21657145#21657145)? I haven't had a chance to try it yet, so I am going to try to use that now

Comment: yes, just remove MoveGestureDetector and RotateGestureDetector and use only ScaleGestureDetector

Comment: I used a matrix(inspired by your code) and gave .setScale the scale and focus[X/Y] and it now zooms as expected

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, but anyway, its good it works... ;-)

Comment: I posted an answer to(make it clear that this issue has been resolved) and to explain what solved the issues. And thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink, here is what I did to solve the problem:

1. Don't override `onTouchEvent` in the class extending ScaleGestureDetector, and don't call OnScaleGestureListener.onScale as it is done automatically by the detector.

This solved the issues I had with zooming.

As for zooming in on a specific area, I had to move away from using .setScale, and use a matrix instead:

```
public void render(Canvas c) {
    super.draw(c);

    if (c != null) {

        c.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);//scale

        //Null the matrix = set to default. 
        c.setMatrix(null);//Past this line, anything rendered is not scaled. 

    }
}
```

(GestureDetector should not override onTouchEvent and make a call to the listener)

And in the listener:

```
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        startScale = detector.getScaleFactor();
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        if(scaleFactor > 2) scaleFactor = 2;//Limit max
        else if(scaleFactor < 0.3f) scaleFactor = 0.3f;//limit min
        scaleFactor = ((float)((int)(scaleFactor * 100))) / 100;//jitter-protection
        scaleMatrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());//setScale, as I don't need to scale several things. 

        return true;
    }
```