# Add limit to canvas.translate

Tags: android, android-canvas, touch-event, ondraw

I'm scaling the canvas, when I move it, it is going out of the screen.

Screenshot of before translating(i.e., when `canvas.onDraw()` executes for the first time)

[image: BEFORE TRANSLATE]

After Move:

[image]

I need some condition to say that don't go beyond this point(x-axis - 20).

```
        canvas.save();
        int maxX, minX;

        minX = /* some condition */;
        maxX = /* some condition */;
        if (mPosX > maxX)
            mPosX = maxX;

        if (mPosX < minX)
            mPosX = minX;

        canvas.translate(mPosX, 0);
        canvas.scale(xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor,
                px / xScaleFactor + left, py / yScaleFactor + canvas.getClipBounds().top);

        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green));
        canvas.drawRect(20, 20, width, height, paint);
```

While moving:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        int eid = ev.getAction();
        switch (eid & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                px = ev.getX();
                py = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = px;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (eid == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || eid == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                    return false;
                }
                pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);

                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                mPosX += dx; 
                invalidate();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                break;
                  .......
```

Kindly help to get some condition which will restrict the rectangle from moving away from the screen. So that the left white space is not created. Every time the canvas invalidates, rectangle should start from position 20 of x-axis.

EDIT:

```
        private Matrix m;
        m = new Matrix();
        m.mapRect(new RectF(20, 0, mPosX, 0));

        // in onDraw()
        canvas.save(); 
        m.setTranslate(mPosX, 0);
        m.setScale(xScaleFactor, yScaleFactor,
                (px + canvas.getClipBounds().left)/ xScaleFactor, (py + canvas.getClipBounds().top)/ yScaleFactor);

        canvas.concat(m);

        paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.green));
        canvas.drawRect(20, 20, width, height, paint);
```

still it is going out

Comment: in such cases it is much easier to work with a `android.graphics.Matrix` api

Comment: You mean, use matrix to control the translate? @pskink

Comment: yes, translate and scale the matrix

Comment: okay. I'm checking that. could you suggest any accurate link if possible

Comment: sure: 
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

Comment: @pskink I read the documentation. Do I need to save the points to matrix and in matrix.postTranslate retrieve the points? How do I proceed. Any suggestions please

Comment: see Canvas#concat

Comment: @pskink could you post the same as an answer with little description and and some code

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830) for some `Matrix` related code

Comment: @pskink I've tried [this](https://github.com/pskink/android-gesture-detectors), the Earth is zooming, moving and rotating. But how do I restrict it to move within the visible area. I mean within the screen. It shouldn't go out of the screen

Comment: use `Matrix#mapRect` and check if mapped rect is outside your screen, if it is modify your matrix accordingly

Comment: @pskink once check the question 'EDIT' part

Comment: @pskink  `m.mapRect(new RectF(30, 0, mPosX, 0));` 
            `canvas.translate(mPosX, 0);` 
            `canvas.setMatrix(m);` is adding the limit to transform. But I can't move to the right end of rectangle. What should be 3rd parameter in `mapRect`

Comment: @pskink whatsoever the value of right parameter in `RectF` it is not allowing to scroll to the right end. canvas.concatMatrix doesn't have any effect on it. So I'm using `setMatrix`. got stuck here. :(

Comment: no, `setMatrix` is wrong here, you should use `concat`

Comment: `concat` isn't stopping the canvas from moving away

Comment: because your matrix is wrong

Comment: m.mapRect(new RectF(20, 0, mPosX, 0)); not like this?

Comment: @pskink okay, I guess I'm little closer. I've added `transform` and `scale` to matrix instead of canvas. And concat the matrix to canvas. still it is not allowing complete right side scrolling. I've added the code in Question

Comment: @pskink Failed to solve it. what should be the matrix? And could you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337835/can-i-access-canvas-elements-separately) once