# drawpicture on canvas (pdfDocument)

Tags: java, android, pdf, canvas

I am able to extract the path of the image but I dont know how to use canvas.drawPicture()

I am able to draw the picture using mipmap, but the size exceeds the size of the pdf page, once I try to set the size of the mutable mipmap something happens to the image and doesn't scale, 
for example the resolution is 2560 x 1600
 once I set the width to 500, i would say alot of copies are display within the 500 it is not reduced.

I am using setDensity() which actually reduce the image but is there a way to include
canvas.drawPicture and modify the dimensions from there or any efficient way?

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        //bitmap.setDensity(2000);

        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);//&lt;--true makes copy mutable



        mutableBitmap.setDensity(2000);
        Toast.makeText(this, mutableBitmap.getWidth() + " " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    canvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap,0,320,null);
   // Toast.makeText(this, centreX + " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I want to be able to control the image size without using density because it depends on. The image size (2560x1600).I want to be able to resize the bitmap or picture so I can position the images on the pdf page

Comment: so use Canvas#drawBitmap with Matrix parameter

Comment: can you explain to me how to use it ? or a good tutorial you have used please!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830 for example