# Touched position and erased position not matched

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap

I am making photo editing application, in my activity I have bitmap that is going to erase on touch when it's not zoomed or rotated its drawing perfectly but after I zoom or rotate bitmap, eraser is not erased at touched points.its erased on some other position according bitmap scaled.

how can I resolve this, please help me.

**Drawingview.java**

```
public class DrawingView extends ImageView implements View.OnTouchListener,MatrixGestureDetector.OnMatrixChangeListener {

private int ERASE = 1;
private int ZOOMTOUCH = 5;



private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
MatrixGestureDetector mgd = new MatrixGestureDetector(matrix, this);
@Override
public void onChange(Matrix matrix) {
invalidate();
}  
public interface ActionListener {
    void onActionCompleted(int i);
}
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    if (bm != null) {
        bmp = bm;
        orgBit = bm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        c2 = new Canvas();
        c2.setBitmap(Bitmap2);

        c2.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);

    }

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.concat(matrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap2,0,0, null);

    if (c2 != null) {
        Paint p;

        if (!updateOnly) {

            if (isTouched) {

                paint = getPaintByMode(MODE, brushSize);
                c2.drawPath(tPath, paint);

                isTouched = false;
            } else if (curIndx >= 0 && drawOnLasso) {
                redrawCanvas();
            }
        }

        if (MODE == ERASE) {
            p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(SupportMenu.CATEGORY_MASK);
            erPaint.setStrokeWidth(updatebrushsize(erps, scale));
            canvas.drawCircle(f887X, f888Y, (float) (brushSize / 2), erPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(f887X, f888Y + ((float) offset), updatebrushsize(ImageUtils.dpToPx(getContext(), 7), scale), p);
        }
        if (MODE == ZOOMTOUCH) {

        }
        updateOnly = false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


    if (MODE == ERASE) {
        f887X = event.getX();
        f888Y = event.getY() - ((float) offset);
        isTouched = true;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case 0:
                paint.setStrokeWidth((float) brushSize);
                tPath = new Path();
                tPath.moveTo(f887X, f888Y);
                drawPath.moveTo(f887X, f888Y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case 1:
                drawPath.lineTo(f887X, f888Y);
                tPath.lineTo(f887X, f888Y);
                invalidate();
                changesIndx.add(curIndx + 1, new Path(tPath));
                brushIndx.add(curIndx + 1, Integer.valueOf(brushSize));
                modeIndx.add(curIndx + 1, Integer.valueOf(MODE));
                vectorPoints.add(curIndx + 1, null);
                lassoIndx.add(curIndx + 1, Boolean.valueOf(insidCutEnable));
                tPath.reset();
                curIndx++;
                clearNextChanges();
                break;
            case 2:
                drawPath.lineTo(f887X, f888Y);
                tPath.lineTo(f887X, f888Y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    if (MODE == ZOOMTOUCH) {
       matrix.invert(inverse);
        float[] pts = {event.getX(), event.getY()};
        inverse.mapPoints(pts);
        mgd.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return true;
}

}
class MatrixGestureDetector {
        private static final String TAG = "MatrixGestureDetector";

        private int ptpIdx = 0;
        private Matrix mTempMatrix = new Matrix();
        private Matrix mMatrix;
        private OnMatrixChangeListener mListener;
        private float[] mSrc = new float[4];
        private float[] mDst = new float[4];
        private int mCount;

        interface OnMatrixChangeListener {
            void onChange(Matrix matrix);
        }

        public MatrixGestureDetector(Matrix matrix, MatrixGestureDetector.OnMatrixChangeListener listener) {
            this.mMatrix = matrix;
            this.mListener = listener;
        }

        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getPointerCount() > 2) {
                return;
            }

            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            int index = event.getActionIndex();

            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    int idx = index * 2;
                    mSrc[idx] = event.getX(index);
                    mSrc[idx + 1] = event.getY(index);
                    mCount++;
                    ptpIdx = 0;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
                        idx = ptpIdx + i * 2;
                        mDst[idx] = event.getX(i);
                        mDst[idx + 1] = event.getY(i);
                    }
                    mTempMatrix.setPolyToPoly(mSrc, ptpIdx, mDst, ptpIdx, mCount);
                    mMatrix.postConcat(mTempMatrix);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onChange(mMatrix);
                    }
                    System.arraycopy(mDst, 0, mSrc, 0, mDst.length);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    if (event.getPointerId(index) == 0) ptpIdx = 2;
                    mCount--;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Zoe that is used scalegesturelistner and iam using matrix

Comment: @Zoe it doesn't have rotation function

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830), and take a look at `Layer#contains` method

Comment: yes @pskink but i have only one bitmap and no layer

Comment: it doesnt matter

Comment: okey than i'll try this

Comment: the usage of `inverse.mapPoints(pts);` is important - it maps one point into another

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159142/discussion-between-jigar-savaliya-and-pskink).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ImageView Scaling and translating issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution thanx to pskink, on this link [Android ImageView Scaling and translating issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue/21657145#21657145)

by using invert matrix in layer#contain method.