# ImageView Scale

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a question around image scale when dragging an ImageView around a device.

The image I have is 5257 pixels x 3423 pixels so its fairly large.  I have coded the mechasim for dragging the image and this works fine (See the code below).

However my problem comes when I run the project and the device shows the image as a zoomed out version of the image.  I want the image to be at "100%" view depth.  ie 5257 pixels x 3423 pixels

When I alter scaleType from matrix to FixXY it fixes the scale however it no longer allows me to drag the image around. I assume this is due to the FixXY expanding the content to the FrameLayout and prevents it from being moved.

So my question is.  Can I use the matrix ScaleType while having a FixXY zoom depth?

I have been looking around this for a while. However most other articles are around keeping the image in the view window setting the iamge to 100% of the view window, which is not what I want.

So hopefully someone can help?

My Layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="21028dp"
    android:layout_height="13696dp"
    android:scaleType="matrix">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="5257dp"
        android:layout_height="3424dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/plan"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"

        android:scaleType="matrix">
    </ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

My code is for this project is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SubScreen6 extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_screen6);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    try{
        view.setOnTouchListener(SubScreen6.this);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        int rotation = 25;

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                            event.getY() - start.y);
                }
                break;
        }
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true; 
    }
```

Comment: use identity `Matrix` then - it will not scale, not translate and not rotate your image at first - but of course you can call any `post*` methods on it to change it

Comment: but if you want the maximum freedom why not to use a custom `View` that draws your `Bitmap` using `Canvas#drawBitmap()` method?

Comment: Excellent thanks for the info.  After you mentioned using a post method I used matrix.setScale(4, 4); after the image had been rendered which seems to have fixed my problem.  I'm quite new to Android Development so will certainly look into a custom View.  Much appreciated!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830 then