# Rotate and scale view proportionally using Matrix

Tags: android, canvas, rect

Initially I am having following following values to draw ovel,

```
RectF(0.0, 0.0, 164.0, 1112.0)
Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 370.97623][0.0, 1.0, 196.02643][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) rect.width(), (int) rect.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.eraseColor(getColor());
```

Here is onDraw method,

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
canvas.save();
canvas.concat(matrix);
canvas.drawOval(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mPaint);
```

Now I am getting following sc:

[image]

after this I am canging Matrix values like this(Actually I am trying to rotate)

```
Matrix{[0.93802166, 0.37798083, 57.083317][-0.37798083, 0.93802166, 278.4423][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
```

And I am applying mapRect to this matrix, like following,

```
RectF rectF2 = new RectF();
matrix.mapRect(rectF2, this.rectF);
```

And my rect2 is `RectF(57.083317, 216.45343, 631.2335, 1321.5223)`

Now again I am creating bitmap using this rect like initial code and invalidating the view and now I am getting following sc:

[image]

But if I didn't recreate the bitmap, I am getting following SC:

[image]

Actually I want this only, How can I achieve this using current rect.

Comment: and? does the rotation and scale work together?

Comment: Yes... Its working fine. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @pskink Can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671113/draw-arrow-head-in-canvas-using-angle