# Zoom Rotate and Drag Bitmap with onTouchEvent

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to **drag**, **zoom** and **rotate** `Bitmap` with two fingers `(onTouchEvent)` but unable to find any solution. There are many solutions to drag, zoom and rotate `imageview` but no solution for `bitmap`.

Need help, Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830

Comment: thanks @pskink for your time, actually i already got the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730914/zoom-rotate-and-drag-bitmap-with-ontouchevent/54762220#54762220

Comment: and where is the `Bitmap` there? they use `ImageViewsetImageMatrix` - did you see the code i posted above? it uses `Bitmap` directly - instead of `ImageView`

Comment: oky, i will try that also

Comment: @pskink, I have tried your solution its perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution to **Drag,** **Rotate** and **Zoom**

---

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnTouchListener {

    // these matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    // we can be in one of these 3 states
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private int mode = NONE;
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float d = 0f;
    private float newRot = 0f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);


    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                        newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float tx = values[0];
                        float ty = values[4];
                        float sx = values[8];
                        float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                        float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
     *
     * @param event
     * @return Degrees
     */
    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            final Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
        } else if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            final Throwable cropError = UCrop.getError(data);
        }
    }

    public void clickedListener(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CropActivity.class));
    }
}
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
    android:onClick="clickedListener"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" >
</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can detect touch gesture and applied them to the bitmap through matrix.

Defined the scale type : ImageView.setImageMatrix(Matrix)
Detect gesture from any view that U want
Use matrix translation for dragging and rotation and matrix scale for zooming using the values that U got in touch event.

BTW there is gesture helper U can use for simplify your work 
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector